# future dates using H2 PARSEDATETIME

Tags: java, h2

```
select PARSEDATETIME('1-Sep-38','DD-MMM-yy') from dual;
```

in H2 database returns

```
1938-09-01 00:00:00.0
```

is there any way to change the config to use current century?

Comment: What version of H2 and Java are you using?

Comment: Using `SimpleDateFormat`, the result is the same, you would need to use `set2DigitYearStart` to adjust the year value, but you'll likely need to do this manually using a `SimpleDateFormat` yourself

Comment: we are using version 1.4.181.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is probably to write you own [user defined function](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#user_defined_functions).